# How to add 'available variables' in openerp salary rule python code?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Currently openerp salary rule has python code writing options where we can grab fields by predefined object (available variables). Like- **contract.wage** gets the value of basic salary field in *contract*.

I want to add more variables for same purpose. Like - I want to have a variable named **grade** by which I can grab the value of that field when payslip runs. **grade.amount** in salary rule python code will get value from my **grade** object's **amount** field.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: you can add an attribute to an object, say `g=Grade()` `c=Contract()` `c.grade = g`

Comment: I am not talking about the attribute, I am talking about the function of calling custom variables.